# How to understand `Iteratee` in play2?

Tags: playframework-2.0, loops

There's a package `play.api.libs.iteratee` in play2, which has a big object `Iteratee` which has more than 1000 lines.

Why play2 need such a big object and how to understand it?

Comment: You should read http://jsuereth.com/scala/2012/02/29/iteratees.html for a decent description of iteratee design.

Comment: Check the Play 2.0 scala advanced documentation https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Iteratees There is a clean and quite long explanation of underneath concepts.

Comment: I just wrote an article trying to explain the concepts of Iteratees provided by Play2 for those who try to discover them. http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/

Comment: What happened to this question? The 3 answers become comments now?

Comment: [Iteratees for imperative programmers](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/11/06/iteratees_for_imperative_programmers.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just wrote an article trying to explain the concepts of Iteratees provided by Play2 for those who try to discover them.

http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/

Here is the conclusion of the article because it appears I must put essential
parts to answer your question. But my article is a whole and your question is also quite large...

> **Anyway, why should I use Iteratee / Enumerator / Enumeratee ?**
>
> I want to tell you that Iteratee / Enumerator / Enumeratee is not a
>   funny tool for people found of functional constructions. They are
>   useful in many domains and once you will understand how they work, I
>   can promise you that you will begin to use it more and more.
>
> Modern web applications are not only dynamically generated pages
>   anymore. Now you manipulate flows of data coming from different
>   sources, in different formats, with different availability timing. You
>   may have to serve huge amount of data to huge number of clients and to
>   work in distributed environments.
>
> Iteratee are made for those cases because there are safe, immutable
>   and very good to deal with data flows in realtime. Let’s tell the
>   buzzword you can see more & more “Realtime WebApp” and Iteratee is
>   associated to that ;)

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to write something to help people discover Iteratees from Play2 because this is something that really changes the way you can design your webapps!

Comment: Please include the relevant parts from your article in this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can understand it better by reading the following:

http://jsuereth.com/scala/2012/02/29/iteratees.html

http://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Iteratees

http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/